# Vue.js Vue-router weird behaviour on browser reload page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I do not understand my vue-router behaviour ...

In the browser, when the home page is displayed , I click on the /users link in the toolbar
The /users page is displayed  correctly..
BUT If I try to reload this /users page ( click on reload browser button ... Chrome currently ) then ..

the /users page is re-displayed AND immediatly after the /home page is dislayed ... as indicated in the console log from my router.beforeEach() function

```
ROUTER BEFORE to:  {name: "Users", meta: {…}, path: "/users", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
ROUTER non protected page:  {name: "Users", meta: {…}, path: "/users", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
ROUTER BEFORE to:  {name: "Home", meta: {…}, path: "/home", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
ROUTER non protected page:  {name: "Home", meta: {…}, path: "/home", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
```

What could be the reason of this weird behaviour ?

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Firebase from 'firebase'
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

function loadView (view) {
  return () => import((/* webpackChunkName: 'view-[request]' */ `@/views/${view}.vue`))
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/users',
      name: 'Users',
      component: loadView('Users')
    }
    ...
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log('ROUTER BEFORE to: ', to)
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    console.log('ROUTER protected page: ', to)
    if (!Firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      console.log('ROUTER user not authenticated')
      next({ path: '/users', query: { redirect: to.fullPath } })
    } else {
      console.log('ROUTER user authenticated')
      next()
    }
  } else {
    console.log('ROUTER non protected page: ', to)
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

Comment: I have a firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)) function... which is run in my main.js ... if no user  then the router push the home page ... I guess I should update it to push to the latest ur ... ??

Answer (score 0):

It's a collateral effect of my  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)) funcction..

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.$router.push('/member')
      } else {
        this.$router.push('/home')
      }
    })
```

I should write it :

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.$router.push('/member')
  } else {
    this.$router.push('/users')
  }
})
```

this function is called whenever I reload the current page...